# FragmentTransaction in Portrait Mode Throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments

First things first, I'm using the compatibility library and here's the error I'm getting:

```
11-22 19:57:09.111: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.bumpBackStackNesting(BackStackRecord.java:518)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:563)
        at 

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1379)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:419)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error only occurs when the application is in PORTRAIT orientation and I'm attempting to  use a FragmentTransaction to hide two other fragments and show a new one. This code gets executed when a user presses a button in the app.

Here's the code that throws (as soon as the commit is called and gets executed the error above is being thrown).

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.hide(fragmentA);
transaction.hide(fragmentB);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PurchaseFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured out what it was. I'm using Roboguice to inject some components and due to some logic not shown above, the fragments were null. If any fragment is null the `transaction.hide(fragment)` then the above exception will occur.

After I fixed the logic error, the fragments were no longer null. At that point the app worked as expected.

Comment: True for me I was using getFragmentManager from fragment and this object did not have the full scope to see the id of a upper fragment since it was inside a PagerFragment and use it ChildFragment it was always returning null, keep an eye on which FragmentManager is best for you,