# Android Support BackStackRecord nullpointerexception

Tags: android

I am working with Fragments, and the commit method call on my FragmentTransaction object is throwing a NullPointerException, what could cause this?

```
FragmentTransaction fragTrans= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragTrans.hide(fragmentA);
            fragTrans.hide(fragmentB);
            fragTrans.commit();
```

If I run the code and comment out the commit, the NPE isn't thrown, so I've narrowed it down to the commit.

The NPE is caused by android.support.v4.BackStackRecord.run

Comment: Are You sure that fragmentA and fragmentB are not null (like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236834/fragmenttransaction-in-portrait-mode-throws-nullpointerexception) ? Full logcat output might be useful also.